# Magento 2: Delete magento product attributes?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, delete

How do you delete created product attributes in Magento 2?

I can't get rid of it. I have couple of Magento product attributes which not needed

Comment: customer attribute or product attribute ?

Comment: product attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete product attributes from below steps:
Go to Admin, click on menu

```
Stores -> Product
```

You have display list of product attributes.
Now click on attributes you want to delete,
new attribute page will display,
click on `delete attribute` button to delete.
Thanks.

Comment: What if the attribute was added by an extension? Is there a way to remove it in Admin?

Comment: If attribute created by an extension is considered as system attribute then there is no way to remove it from admin.

Answer (score 25):

If you do not see the delete attribute button then that means the table column **'is_user_defined'** in the **eav_attribute** table is set to **0**.
By changing this to **1** it will show the delete button.

If you do not know where to go to find the attribute then you can follow the answers.
In the admin Stores->Attributes->Products

Answer (score 3):

You can remove unused product attributes in Magento 2 by using command line as well.

> php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:cleanup

Sees more details command line catalog:product:attributes:cleanup by using command line help or option -h:

> php bin/magento help catalog:product:attributes:cleanup

OR  use

> php bin/magento catalog:product:attributes:cleanup -h

Let me know if you still have any issue.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Product attributes Navigation in admin for delete
`Stores->Attributes` click on `Products`  here you can see all attributes just click on your select attribute and click on `delete attribute` button.

Answer (score 2):

The `eav_attribute` table set from `0` to `1` worked perfectly. I had migrated from Magento 1 and had all these left over attributes that needed to be removed but I could not because when they were migrated they treated those attributes like system attributes and therefore could not delete.

That last comment changing the `eav_attribute` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to delete product attribute from backend navigate to

`Stores -> Attributes -> Product`

click on desired attribute and in next page you will see **Delete Attribute** button in the top bar, click on it to delete attribute.

If you do not see the delete attribute button then it means the table column '**is_user_defined**' in the **eav_attribute** table is set to **0**. By changing this to **1** it will show the delete button.

If you had migrated from Magento 1 then this attributes were considered as system attributes and therefore no delete attribute button is displayed in backend.

Run below query in database to set this value for multiple attributes

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_user_defined` = 1 WHERE attribute_code IN ('attribute_1','attribute_2');
```